# Merge several 2D plot into one 3D plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have three 2D plot that depends on the same x-variable.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1v7U.jpg)
and these 3 plots are for different resolutions. the 3rd dimension will be low medium and high.

I want them to plot as in the example. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming your 3 vectors have the same dimensions:

1. Merge your 3 vectors in matrix `data` as follows: `data = [vector1; vector2; vector3];`
2. Use the surf function to plot the resulting matrix: `surf(data);`